# Android XMLparse to Arraylist

Tags: android, xml, image, arraylist, xml-parsing

Sorry, if I've made things confusing. I edited the whole question.

I'm using XMLPARSER for my urls that is hosted on my webserver.

I would like to parse my url list from `url.add(map);` into `intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);` So that i could retrieve urls from my XMLparser. Please guide me how to do it with codes. My attempt shows error

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type java.util.HashMap
>   cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

        static final String URL = "http://*******";


        static final String KEY_LIST = "list";
        static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ac_home);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> url = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_LIST);

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                url.add(map); // <***** Set the results from here to imageUrls
            }

        imageUrls = (String[]) url.toArray(new String[0]); // <----***Error****

        }
        public void onImageGridClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void onImagePagerClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Anyone free to take a look on my codes?

Comment: Be specific in your question "What you want ?", your question is confusing. If you want to add only XML-parser URLs then don't add URLs from heavy_images.xml, and one more thing understand things not directly copy it from GitHub or any code source.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question. Please guide me Android Coder

Comment: I've tried to put in this imageUrls = (String[]) url.toArray(new String[0]); but it shows error "java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type java.util.HashMap cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]"

Comment: for this you have to set type of arraylist to String instead of hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    String[] imageUrls;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_home);
        ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url_link = new URL("http:******");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url_link.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("list");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element)node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("thumb_url");
                Element nameElement = (Element)nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

                url.add(nameList.item(0).getNodeValue());
            }
            imageUrls = (String[]) url.toArray(new String[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }
    public void onImageGridClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onImagePagerClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Android Coder . You deserve 5 stars from me. THANKS a million times